# Can't convert from Fixnum into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the rmeetup gem to grab information from the meetup group.
When I try to pull information from the results, all works except time and I receive a 'can't convert Fixnum into String'

My code:

```
   <% RMeetup::Client.api_key = "APICODE" 
    results = RMeetup::Client.fetch(:open_events, { topic: "business", city: "syracuse", state: "ny"}) %>
    <%= results.count %><br/>
    <%= results.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.name %> 
        <%= result.id %>
        <%= result.waitlist_count %>
        <%= result.utc_offset %>
        <%= result.created %>
        <%= result.time.to_s %>

        <hr/

    <% end %>
```

What is strange is that the .id, .waitlist_count, .utf_offset, .created all work and all are numbers, but .time wont work and will not allow to me convert to string.

Comment: Technically, you shouldn't even have to call `to_s` on it explicitly since `<%= %>` is already calling the `to_s` on it under the hood.

Comment: You are right, I thought it would fix the problem but it didn't. It won't convert Fixnum to String. Is there a way to force it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every object, going all the way up to `Object`, contains a `to_s` method on it.

```
Object.new.to_s #=> "#<Object:0x1668fa8>"
```

This means that your problem isn't in the `to_s` method that is getting called by `<%= ... %>`.

Looking at the [`event.rb`](https://github.com/jdpace/rmeetup/blob/master/lib/rmeetup/type/event.rb) file in the rmeetup gem, you'll notice:

```
self.time = DateTime.parse(event['time'])
```

This means that the instance variable you are calling with `result.time` is of the type `DateTime`. Also note that it is getting set by using [`DateTime.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) which takes a string. So what happens when you pass a Fixnum to `DateTime.parse`?

```
DateTime.parse(42) #=> 'no implicit conversation of Fixnum into String'
```

According to the [MeetUp API](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/open_events/%E2%80%8E), the `time` is returned as:

> UTC start time of the event, in milliseconds since the epoch

The original RMeetup gem was last updated 5 years ago. Are you using a more recent fork? If not, it could be that the gem has simply broken as new APIs are released by MeetUp. I would suggest either finding a more up-to-date gem for accessing the MeetUp API or fork the gem and make your own alterations.

Comment: Hey Charles,Thanks for the reply! Turns out there was a problem with the gem (it's outdated) and did not convert the time in the manner expected.